# Execute something when multiple Singles finish (aka combineLatest for Single)

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I want to execute something when both `units` and `variables` are set (through `Single<T>`, NOT `Observable`). How to do that?

```
// getUserId(), getSomething(), getSomethingElse() all return Single<T>

getUserId().flatMap { getSomething(it) }.subscribe({ data -> units = data }) 
getUserId().flatMap { getSomethingElse(it) }.subscribe({ data -> variables = data }) 

execute(units, variables)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator:

```
val name = Single.just("Jake")
val age = Single.just(26)

Single.zip<String, Int, String>(name, age, BiFunction { n, a -> "$n is $a years old" })
        .subscribe { result -> print(result) }
```

will print "Jake is 26 years old".

Comment: Mine is `Single`, not `Observable`, so doesn't have `comebineLatest` on it

Comment: It is not really a stream then... you should specify it in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out after digging around `combineLatest`